# Is List in Kotlin a LinkedList?

Tags: java, arraylist, linked-list, kotlin

The most popular lists in Java are `ArrayList` and `LinkedList`.

In Kotlin I see `ArrayList` and `List`. Is `List` actually a `LinkedList`? For example

```
val list = listof("1st", "2nd")
```

Comment: It is not obvious,  It inherited from the abstract list but implementation . You can see java version of Kotlin code If you use intellij (tools -> Kotlin -> show byte code )

Answer (score 15):

If you use [`listOf`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/list-of.html), you'll get some sort of `List` implementation, with the read-only [`List`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/-list/index.html) interface, containing the elements you've provided as arguments. By using this function you're implying that you don't care about how it's implemented. <strike>In reality, this will probably still be a `java.util.ArrayList` under the hood if you're on the JVM.</strike> As @Zabuza pointed out in comments here, it's actually backed by an `Arrays.ArrayList`, which is a slightly different class.

If you use [`mutableListOf`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/mutable-list-of.html), again, you're only saying you want *something* containing your elements that implements [`MutableList`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/-mutable-list/index.html), but the implementation is up to the standard library. Again, this is currently backed by an `ArrayList`, but this is an implementation detail.

There are a couple functions that explicitly return a more specific type, if you do need them. There's [`arrayListOf`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/array-list-of.html), [`sortedSetOf`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/sorted-set-of.html), [`linkedMapOf`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/linked-map-of.html), and a couple more - there doesn't happen to be a `linkedListOf`, but you could probably implement it yourself if you need one and don't want to use the `LinkedList` constructor.

The more general `listOf` and `mutableListOf` are preferrable if there's a change you'll share your code between platforms later - as these are parts of the standard library, they can return an `ArrayList` on the JVM, but different platform specific implementations if you compile to JavaScript or Native.

Answer (score 7):

It's neither a `LinkedList` nor an `ArrayList`. Based on the [source code](https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin/blob/1.2.50/libraries/stdlib/jvm/src/kotlin/collections/CollectionsJVM.kt#L18):

```
public fun <T> listOf(element: T): List<T> = java.util.Collections.singletonList(element)
```

or, for multiple elements:

```
public fun <T> listOf(vararg elements: T): List<T> = if (elements.size > 0) elements.asList() else emptyList()
```

This last piece of code calls `ArraysUtilJVM`, which in turn calls `Arrays.asList()`, which returns an `Arrays.ArrayList` instance. However, that's an implementation detail and it might change in the future. The important thing is that the resulting object implements the `List` interface (i.e., it's immutable).

Comment: ... which is not what is generally known as `ArrayList` (*dynamic array*). It's a fixed-size wrapper around an array.

Answer (score 5):

Just tried printing the type,

### *  for one element it's a SingletonList

```
val list = listOf("a")
println(list.javaClass)
```

> output: class java.util.Collections$SingletonList

### *  for more than one element it's an ArrayList

```
val list = listOf("a", "b", "c")
println(list.javaClass)
```

> output: class java.util.Arrays$ArrayList

Answer (score 4):

> List in kotlin is not a LinkedList
>
> According to official docs- The Kotlin List type is an
>   interface that provides read-only operations like size, get and so on.
>   Like in Java, it inherits from Collection and that in turn inherits
>   from Iterable.

**listOf()** is a methods from the standard Kotlin library to create an **immutable list**. The **listOf()** method is implemented using an **array list** in kotlin.

Follow this [official document link](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/collections.html) for more details.

Comment: I think it's important to highlight that `Arrays#ArrayList` is not what is generally known as `ArrayList` (`java.util.ArrayList`). It's just a fixed-size wrapper around an array. Which throws exceptions for methods like `add`.

Comment: @Zabuza you are right it throws exception but the official docs says "Currently, the listOf method is implemented using an array list, but in future more memory-efficient fully immutable collection types could be returned that exploit the fact that they know they can't change."

Answer (score 0):

If you trace the source code

**Collections.kt**

```
/**
 * Returns a new read-only list of given elements.  The returned list is serializable (JVM).
 * @sample samples.collections.Collections.Lists.readOnlyList
 */
public fun <T> listOf(vararg elements: T): List<T> = if (elements.size > 0) elements.asList() else emptyList()
```

Then
**_Arrays.kt**

```
/**
 * Returns a [List] that wraps the original array.
 */
public expect fun <T> Array<out T>.asList(): List<T>
```

Then you'll find that it's Kotlin's Array, wrapped around by Kotlin's List interface, let's call it "Kotlin's Array List"

"Kotlin's Array List" may or may not be the same as Java's array - I guess it is in a Java (JVM) or Android environment (Dalvik or ART)